# fetchcontroller is not getting value in facebook chat ios app

Tags: ios5, core-data, xcode4.2, nsfetchrequest, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have deleted all of the entries stored in Core Data at the time of logout in my FBChat application by using the methods as follows.

```
//delete persistance.......         



 if ([__persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores] == nil)
     return;

 [self.managedObjectContext reset];
 [self.managedObjectContext lock];

 NSPersistentStore *store = [[self.persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores] lastObject];

 if (![self.persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:store error:&error]) {
     NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
     abort();
 }  


// Delete file

 if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:store.URL.path]) {
     if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:store.URL.path error:&error]) {
         NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
         abort();
     } 
 }

 __persistentStoreCoordinator = nil;

 __persistentStoreCoordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
 [self.managedObjectContext unlock];
```

But When I am log in again, `fetchcontroller` not getting the values. I have set the `fetchcontroller=nil` while logout. The delegate methods for the `fetchcontroller` are getting called at the login time.

If anybody having idea then please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. After deleting everything, you are not getting values. If your fetched results controller is created lazily (code not shown, but that is usually the design pattern), it will create itself when needed.

No surprises here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I have used another method for clearing the core data.now its working fine